# How do I filter elements which contain a string with an AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm obtaining a list of elements in classes and I'd like to filter out any class which does not contain a specific word in the innerHTML. Currently, I've managed to filter out the words however I can't seem to obtain the whole string, only part of it. Here's what I've got:

```
htmlData = $(htmlData).find(".Description").html("Fruit");
```

All this does is return "FruitFruitFruitFruitFruit..." when I'd like to obtain the whole string which the word is in. Anyone know how to do it? Thanks.

Comment: IT can append in to your string, not replace

**$(htmlData).find(".Description").append("Fruit");**

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the assignment in an if, in which you're checking if the string is contained in the Text.

```
if($(htmlData).find(".Description").text().indexOf("Fruit") === -1){
  htmlData = $(htmlData).find(".Description").html();
}
```

the `indexOf` function returns the index of where the string was found first. If it wasn't found, it returns -1.

Comment: Not exactly what I was after, but I should have been more specific. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I hope that this is what you meant..

```
var arr = [];
$.each($(htmlData).find(".Description"), function(_, jqElem){
    var content = jqElem.html();
    if (content.indexOf("Fruit") !== -1 ) {
        arr.push(content);
    }
})
```